# The inverse of bijective analytic function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

My original question is some inverse function theorem for analytic function.

> If $f$ is analytic at $z_0$ with $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ then there exists an analytic function $g$ with $f\circ g=1$ in some nbd of $z_0$.

So far, I've shown,

> Proposition. If $f$ is analytic at $z_0$ with $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ then $f$ is one to one in some nbd of $z_0$.

So if I let $U$ be such nbd of $z_0$ in the above proposition, by the open mapping theorem, $f(U)=:V$ is open so I have some set theoretic inverse $g:U\to V$ with $f\circ g = 1$ and $g\circ f =1$. Now what I have to show is $g$ is analytic on $V$.

My attempt: Let $w\in V$ and $h$ near $0$ so that $w+h\in V$. Then I need to show
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(w+h)-g(w)}{h}$$
exists. As $g\circ f= 1$, I have $z\in U$ and $\tilde{h}$ near $0$ such that $z+\tilde{h}\in U$ such that $f(z) = w$ and $f(z+\tilde{h}) = w+h$.
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g(f(z+\tilde{h}))-g(f(z))}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{z+\tilde{h}-z}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\tilde{h}}{h}$$
the problem here is I don't know the relation between $h$ and $\tilde{h}$. Is my approach correct? Could you help?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/854805/42969.