# Does a p-adic analytic function have an analytic inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, p-adic-number-theory, analytic-functions

Suppose we have a function $f$ defined on a disk in the field $\mathbb Q_p$, given by an absolutely convergent power series, with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=1$:

$$\mathbb Q_p\ni f(x)=x+\sum_{n\geq2}a_nx^n,\quad|x|\leq R>0$$
$$\mathbb R\ni\sum_{n\geq2}|a_n|R^n<\infty$$

Are there disks of (positive) radii $S$ and $r\leq R$, and a function $g$, also given by an absolutely convergent power series, such that $g(f(x))=x$ for all $|x|\leq r$, and $f(g(y))=y$ for all $|y|\leq S$?

$$g(y)=y+\sum_{n\geq2}b_ny^n,\quad|y|\leq S$$
$$\sum_{n\geq2}|b_n|S^n<\infty$$

(Assuming it is true) I'd actually like a uniform proof that works for $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$, or $\mathbb Q_p$. See [Is the inverse of a real analytic function still analytic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359330/is-the-inverse-of-a-real-analytic-function-still-analytic) and [If $f'(z_0)\neq 0$ then $f$ has an holomorphic inverse.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854636/if-fz-0-neq-0-then-f-has-an-holomorphic-inverse) for proofs specific to the complex field. See [Composition of real-analytic functions is real-analytic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1197737/composition-of-real-analytic-functions-is-real-analytic) for a uniform proof of the type I'm looking for.

By expanding the formal power series $g(f(X))$, I can see that the required coefficients $b_n$ exist and are unique. But I can't see that $g(y)$ converges for some $y\neq0$.

Comment: I don't know very much about analysis in the non-Archimedean setting, but over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, one thing you can do to prove this is use the fact that the function is $C^1$ and has a differential which is a similarity of the (complex) tangent space (rotation + scaling), so the ordinary inverse function theorem works and the property of being a similarity is preserved. I wonder if there is any similar thing you can do in this setting?

Comment: Check out these [lecture notes of Peter Schneider's](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/lectnotes/p-adic-analysis.pdf),proposition 6.4 (relying especially on proposition 5.9).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg - Thanks. But that definition of analyticity only requires convergence, while I require absolute convergence. To show the difference: $$f(x)=x+2x^2+2x^3+4x^4+4x^5+4x^6+4x^7\\+8x^8+8x^9+8x^{10}+8x^{11}+8x^{12}+8x^{13}+8x^{14}+8x^{15}+16x^{16}+\cdots$$ converges $2$-adically at $f(1)=-1/3$, but doesn't converge absolutely: $$1+\frac12+\frac12+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14+\frac14\\+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac18+\frac1{16}+\cdots$$ $$=\infty$$

Comment: On second thought, convergence for $|x|\leq R$ implies absolute convergence for $|x|<R$, so the two definitions should be equivalent. But the proof of 5.9 still uses the strong triangle inequality. I think I should edit the question, to put less focus on $p$-adic fields. Thanks anyway for those notes.

Comment: (There may not be an $x_*$ with $|x_*|_p=R$. I should have said this instead: Convergence at $x_*$ implies absolute convergence at $x$ for $|x|<|x_*|$, so the two definitions should be equivalent.)

Comment: Okay, I've found my "uniform proof", and posted it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3134267/proof-that-the-inverse-of-an-analytic-function-is-analytic-which-uses-only-real